# Trying to add "this" object to an array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, object, this, appendchild

I'm trying to make it so when you push a button you add a note to the page. When I push the button, the new note flashes. I'm trying to get it to stay.

When I use a regular bracket object the new note stays. I could just switch to using one, but I wanna know if it's possible to make it work with a "this" object before switching.

The button used to add the note is under the "Note Drop-down" button

```js
   var dummyNotes = [];

   class NewNote {
        constructor(id, title, details, date) {
            this.id = id;
            this.title = title;
            this.details = details;
            this.date = date;
            this.titleFormat = function() {
                return `<span class="titleSpan">
                            <input type="text" class="noteTitle inputControls" value="${this.title}" maxlength="50">
                            <label class="editLabel detailScript">0/50</label>
                            <label class="editLabel errorMessage">Character limit reached!</label>
                            <span class="noteButtons">                  
                                <button class="editTitle">Edit</button>
                                <button class="deleteNote">Delete</button>
                            </span>
                            <span class="noteInfo">
                                <label class="theDate">${this.date}</label>
                                <label class="theID">${this.id}</label>
                            </span>
                        </span>`;
            }
            this.detailsFormat = function() {
                return `<span class="detailsSpan">
                            <details><summary>Click for Details</summary>
                                <textarea class="noteDetails inputControls" maxlength="100">${this.details}</textarea>
                                <label class="editLabel detailScript">0/100</label>
                                <label class="editLabel errorMessage">Character limit reached!</label>
                                <button class="editDetails">Edit</button>
                            </details>  
                        </span>`;
                        }
                     }
                    }

    let newNoteInput = document.getElementById("newNoteInput");


    newNoteInput.addEventListener('submit', addANote);


    function addANote(){
        /*If this fails, just copy paste what's under, insert values */
        const pushNote = new NewNote(generateID(), newNoteTitle.value, newNoteDetails.value, dateNote.toLocaleDateString());
        dummyNotes.push(pushNote);
        addNewNote(pushNote);
        newNoteTitle.value = "";
        newNoteDetails.value = "";

    }

    function addNewNote(pushNote) {
        const theNewNote = document.createElement("div");
        theNewNote.classList.add("newNote");
        const theNewNoteForm = document.createElement("form");
        theNewNoteForm.classList.add("noteForm");
        theNewNote.appendChild(theNewNoteForm);
        theNewNoteForm.innerHTML = pushNote.titleFormat() + pushNote.detailsFormat();
        noteList.appendChild(theNewNote); /*APPEND CHILD to get every item on the list*/
    }

    function init() {
        dummyNotes.forEach(addNewNote);
        noteList.innerHTML = "";
    }

    init();
```

```html
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Notes.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial-scale="1.0">
        <title>Notes</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="noteContainer">
                <details id="buttonContainer">
                    <summary id="toggleContainer">Note Drop-Down</summary>
                    <span id="newNoteToggle">
                        <form id="newNoteInput">
                            <span>
                                <input type="text" id="newNoteTitle" class="inputControls" placeholder="Title" maxlength="50">
                                <label class="newLabel detailScript">0/50</label>
                                <label class="newLabel errorMessage">Character limit reached!</label>
                            </span>
                            <span>
                                <input type="textarea" id="newNoteDetails" class="inputControls" placeholder="Details" maxlength="100">
                                <label class="newLabel detailScript">0/100</label>
                                <label class="newLabel errorMessage">Character limit reached!</label>
                            </span>
                            <button id="addButton">Add New Note</button>
                        </form>
                    </span>
                </details>
                <div id="noteList">
                    <div class="newNote">
                        <form class="noteForm">
                        <span class="titleSpan">
                            <input type="text" class="noteTitle" value="Note Title">
                            <button class="editTitle">Edit</button>
                            <button class="deleteNote">Delete</button>
                            <label class="theDate">The Date</label>
                            <label class="theDate">ID</label>
                        </span>
                        <span class="detailsSpan">
                            <details><summary>Click for Details</summary>
                                <textarea class="noteDetails"></textarea>
                                <button class="editDetails">Edit</button>
                                <span id="wordCount"></span>
                            </details>  
                        </span>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div id="searchContainer">
                <details id="searchForm">
                    <summary><h4>Search Notes</h4></summary>
                    <form>
                    <input id="searchDate" type="date" placeholder="Date">
                    <input id="searchTitle" type="text" placeholder="Title">
                    <button id ="searchButton">Search</button>
                    </form>
                </details>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="Notes.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible to create snippet of your problem? I the example code you've mentioned, generateID and dateNote etc functions are not defined.

Comment: Are you sure your entire page isn't reloading on submit? It doesn't appear that you're running `e.preventDefault()` anywhere after catching the form submission. You could probably just return `false` from `addANote()`

Comment: I'll create a snippet in a moment, but first let me see if the preventDefault function thing works

Comment: preventDefault worked! Thank you so much Sean Kendle!!

Comment: I've posted my answer, please accept and upvote

Comment: Also, I changed your question into an actual snippet

Answer (score 2):

Yep, as I suspected, your form was definitely posting without preventing default.

Please review the code, I've commented everywhere I made changes.

```js
//was getting errors for these variables not being defined.
var dummyNotes = [],
  dateNote = new Date();

   class NewNote {
        constructor(id, title, details, date) {
            this.id = id;
            this.title = title;
            this.details = details;
            this.date = date;
            this.titleFormat = function() {
                return `<span class="titleSpan">
                            <input type="text" class="noteTitle inputControls" value="${this.title}" maxlength="50">
                            <label class="editLabel detailScript">0/50</label>
                            <label class="editLabel errorMessage">Character limit reached!</label>
                            <span class="noteButtons">                  
                                <button class="editTitle">Edit</button>
                                <button class="deleteNote">Delete</button>
                            </span>
                            <span class="noteInfo">
                                <label class="theDate">${this.date}</label>
                                <label class="theID">${this.id}</label>
                            </span>
                        </span>`;
            }
            this.detailsFormat = function() {
                return `<span class="detailsSpan">
                            <details><summary>Click for Details</summary>
                                <textarea class="noteDetails inputControls" maxlength="100">${this.details}</textarea>
                                <label class="editLabel detailScript">0/100</label>
                                <label class="editLabel errorMessage">Character limit reached!</label>
                                <button class="editDetails">Edit</button>
                            </details>  
                        </span>`;
                        }
                     }
                    }

    let newNoteInput = document.getElementById("newNoteInput");

    //changed this function to run an anonymous function, prevent default and then call addANote():
    newNoteInput.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      addANote();
    });


    function addANote(){
        /*If this fails, just copy paste what's under, insert values */
        const pushNote = new NewNote(generateID(), newNoteTitle.value, newNoteDetails.value, dateNote.toLocaleDateString());
        dummyNotes.push(pushNote);
        addNewNote(pushNote);
        newNoteTitle.value = "";
        newNoteDetails.value = "";
        
        return false;
    }

    function addNewNote(pushNote) {
        const theNewNote = document.createElement("div");
        theNewNote.classList.add("newNote");
        const theNewNoteForm = document.createElement("form");
        theNewNoteForm.classList.add("noteForm");
        theNewNote.appendChild(theNewNoteForm);
        theNewNoteForm.innerHTML = pushNote.titleFormat() + pushNote.detailsFormat();
        noteList.appendChild(theNewNote); /*APPEND CHILD to get every item on the list*/
    }

    function init() {
        dummyNotes.forEach(addNewNote);
        noteList.innerHTML = "";
    }
    
    //was getting error due to this function not existing, so I threw this in here:
    function generateID() {
      return parseInt(Math.random() * 10000);
    }

    init();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Notes.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial-scale="1.0">
        <title>Notes</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="noteContainer">
                <details id="buttonContainer">
                    <summary id="toggleContainer">Note Drop-Down</summary>
                    <span id="newNoteToggle">
                        <form id="newNoteInput">
                            <span>
                                <input type="text" id="newNoteTitle" class="inputControls" placeholder="Title" maxlength="50">
                                <label class="newLabel detailScript">0/50</label>
                                <label class="newLabel errorMessage">Character limit reached!</label>
                            </span>
                            <span>
                                <input type="textarea" id="newNoteDetails" class="inputControls" placeholder="Details" maxlength="100">
                                <label class="newLabel detailScript">0/100</label>
                                <label class="newLabel errorMessage">Character limit reached!</label>
                            </span>
                            <button id="addButton">Add New Note</button>
                        </form>
                    </span>
                </details>
                <div id="noteList">
                    <div class="newNote">
                        <form class="noteForm">
                        <span class="titleSpan">
                            <input type="text" class="noteTitle" value="Note Title">
                            <button class="editTitle">Edit</button>
                            <button class="deleteNote">Delete</button>
                            <label class="theDate">The Date</label>
                            <label class="theDate">ID</label>
                        </span>
                        <span class="detailsSpan">
                            <details><summary>Click for Details</summary>
                                <textarea class="noteDetails"></textarea>
                                <button class="editDetails">Edit</button>
                                <span id="wordCount"></span>
                            </details>  
                        </span>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div id="searchContainer">
                <details id="searchForm">
                    <summary><h4>Search Notes</h4></summary>
                    <form>
                    <input id="searchDate" type="date" placeholder="Date">
                    <input id="searchTitle" type="text" placeholder="Title">
                    <button id ="searchButton">Search</button>
                    </form>
                </details>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="Notes.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: One more question. I just added a remove function to the deleteNote button. When pressed, it's supposed to remove the note that corresponds to that id. But when it's pressed, all of the notes are removed.

Here is the new remove question
`function removeNote(id){ dummyNotes = dummyNotes.filter(pushNote => pushNote.id != id); init();
}`

It was added to the delete button like this
`<button class="deleteNote" onclick="removeNote(${this.id})">Delete</button>`

Comment: `this.id` isn't going to give you the id of the note, because `this` is the delete button in that case. I'll bet if you `console.log` the id, it's `null`, and then you're getting back the same array when you `filter()` it. Try `this.closest(".newNote").id`, and see if when you `console.log` the `id` you get what you expect. Also, I would avoid inline javascript mixed with regular JS. Write listeners instead of inline `onclick` handlers... personal preference, but it's easier to debug for me.

Comment: No dice. Console log says "this.closest" isn't a function

Comment: I just noticed. I console logged the dummyNotes array itself within the removeNotes function. When I click the delete button, the log shows that the array elements are there; that only the element matching the "id" of the note I deleted is gone. But even though the array is there, it won't show on the page.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do to make the remove button work was write init like this:

```
function init() {
    noteList.innerHTML = "";
    dummyNotes.forEach(addNewNote);  
}
```

noteList.innerHTML just needed to be on top!

Comment: You should post new questions separately from your original question